# Can I set a timeout and number of retries on a specific pipeline request?

Tags: scala, pipeline, spray, spray-client

When using spray's pipelining to make an HTTP request like this:

```
val urlpipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[String]
urlpipeline { Get(url) }
```

is there a way to specify a timeout for the request and the number of times it should retry for that specific request?

All the documentation I've found only references doing in a config (and even then I can't seem to get it to work).

thx

Comment: Which spray version is that? In recent versions you can use it like it is described here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-M8/spray-client/. See the example with `HostConnectorSetup`. One parameter of `HostConnectorSetup` is a settings parameter (not shown in the example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### With the configuration file

I use Spray 1.2.0 in an Akka system. Inside my actor, I import the existing Akka system so I can use the default Akka configuration file.

```
implicit val system = context.system
import context.dispatcher
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive
```

Now you can change the configuration in `application.conf`.

```
spray.can.host-connector {
    max-connections = 10
    max-retries = 3
    max-redirects = 0
    pipelining = off
    idle-timeout = 30 s
    client = ${spray.can.client}
}
```

#### In code

It is possible to change the settings in code using the HostConnectorSetup, but you have to define all parameters. (Based on the [spray usage example](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-client/#usage).)

```
val pipeline: Future[SendReceive] =
for (
  Http.HostConnectorInfo(connector, _) <-
  IO(Http) ? Http.HostConnectorSetup("www.spray.io", port = 80, settings = Some(new HostConnectorSettings(maxConnections = 3, maxRetries = 3, maxRedirects = 0, pipelining = false, idleTimeout = 5 seconds, connectionSettings = ClientConnectionSettings(...))))
) yield sendReceive(connector)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the easiest way to override the default timeout in code is to use the implicit `futureTimeout` argument to the `sendReceive` method. The data type of that parameter is `akka.util.Timeout`. So, if you wanted a 120 second timeout instead of the default 60 seconds, you can do this...

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(120 seconds)
val urlpipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[String]
urlpipeline { Get(url) }
```

However, I don't see any parameter that would allow your client code to change the maximum number of retries in a similar fashion.

Comment: Also, I found this article to be very helpful - http://kamon.io/teamblog/2014/11/02/understanding-spray-client-timeout-settings/

Comment: / ! \ This does not affect the connection timeout, this only affects the ask timeout, causing an exception to be raised if the specified timeout is reached- the underlying connection will not be cancelled. See the above link by Daryl.